# get index of subtable from function args in lua

Tags: function, variables, lua, arguments

Im trying to return the value of an index of a table which is inside of another table and am doing so using the args given when a function is run so that the arg resolves to a variable name.

```
function getsubindex(varname,index)
    local tbl = {}
    tbl.first = 99
    tbl.subTbl = {10,20,30}

    if not index then
        return tbl[varname]
    else
        return tbl[varname[index]]
    end
end
```

returning `tbl[varname]` works because you can use a string as an index for example.

```
getsubindex("first")
```

Would return `99`, but I need to get into the subTbl take this example of running the func.

```
getsubindex("subTbl",2)
```

I'm wanting this to return `20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
return tbl[varname[index]]
```

to:

```
return tbl[varname][index]
```